# Print the parameter of an object

Tags: java, constructor

`WordDef` is an object that accepts `String word`, and `String definition` as parameters. `dictionary` is an ArrayList of `WordDef` objects. I need to print out just the `definition` parameter based on the `word` the user inputs. This is what I have tried:

```
//in a separate class
public String toString() {

return word + "\t" + definition;
}
```

```
String d = "";
System.out.println("Enter the word you would like to see the definition of: "); 
String w = reader.nextLine();
            for(int x = 0; x < dictionary.size(); x++) {
                if(dictionary.get(x).equals(w)) {

                    d.toString(); //I know this wouldn't work but I was trying to see if anything would print at all

                }
                System.out.println("The definition for " + w + " is: " + d.toString());
```

I'm unsure how to search for specific parameters of an object. Thanks

Comment: You might want to try storing your word-definition pairs in a `Map`. That way, you only need to call `map.get(word)` and it will return the definition

Comment: is there a way to do this without `map`? this is for an assignment and although it would be much easier, I'm not allowed to use them

Comment: From what I see, you need to do is change `dictionary.get(x).equals(w)` to `dictionary.get(x).word.equals(w)`, and then change `d.toString()` to `d = dictionary.get(x).word`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Map or a HashMap would be a better way to go for efficiency and convenience, but if you want to use an ArrayList, use:

```
if(dictionary.get(x).getWord().equals(w) {
System.out.println(dictionary.get(x).getDefinition())
}
```

getWord() and getDefinition() are just how you might have defined accessors.  If word and definition are not private, you can access them directly with .word and .definition. But you probably want them to be private.
You just needed the code to access properties at that index in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works assuming there is a getter for `definition` class member.

```
System.out.println("Enter the word you would like to see the definition of: "); 
String w = reader.nextLine();
for(int x = 0; x < dictionary.size(); x++) {
    if(dictionary.get(x).word.equals(w)) {
      System.out.println("The definition for " + w + " is: " + dictionary.get(x).getDefinition());            
    }
}
```

If WordDef class is somewhat like this :

```
public  class WordDef {
    private String word;
    private String definition ;

    public Student(String word, String definition){
        this.word=word;
        this.definition=definition;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Word : "+word+", Definition : " +definition;
    }
}
```

You can override toString for WordDef and call `System.out.println(wordDefObject)` it will work.